# Hover on specific post should show the title of only that post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, hover

I'm using Wordpress for my website. What I'm trying to achieve is that if I hover on a specific post, it should show the title of that very post. But what it does right now, is that if I hover on one post, it displays the title of all the posts.

The code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post">
            <div>

                <div class="post-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php if ( p75HasThumbnail($post->ID) ) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo p75GetThumbnail($post->ID, 200, 108); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="200" height="108" />
                <?php  } ?>
                </a></div>

       <div class="post-content" style="display:none;">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>    
                </div>

                <div class="post-footer">
                    <small>
                    In: <?php the_category(' | ') ?>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--    -->


    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <?php next_posts_link('<div class="post archiveTitle "><div>&larr; Older</div></div>') ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('<div class="post archiveTitle "><div>Newer &rarr;</div></div>') ?>


    <?php else : ?>

    <div class="post">
        <div>
            <h1>Not Found</h1>
            <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
        </div>
     </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.post-header').hover(function(){
            $('.post-content').show();
        }, function(){
            $('.post-content').hide();    
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if it's this, what you want to achieve:

```
$('.post-header').hover(function(){
    $('.post-content', $(this).parent()).show();
}, function(){
    $('.post-content').hide();    
});
```

Now only the post-content of the currently hovered post is shown.